# Conditionally loading javascript script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, loading

I have a chrome extension that have a settings page. In the settings page I want to have preview and save buttons. I want to be able to pass temporary options object to my APPLICATION. How can I do it so that i don't have to rewrite APPLICATION twice? How to pass information to html page that this time it should access LocalStorage['permanent_settings'] and other LocalStorage['temporary_settings'], and render content using that object as a settings object. Also I want my code to execute locally, so I don't want any PHP etc.

Comment: Please provide more detail.  Maybe some of your existing code.  It's not clear what the problem is you are having.

Comment: If Chrome crashes before changing read_from to permanent_settings at exit, your plug-in will default to this source on start-up. This way, even if you don't get to press Save or Preview, you obtain reading from permanent_settings as the implicit behavior. See my edited answers for details.

Answer (score 2):

You can add your conditions to this method, which allows you to dynamically add an external javascript file:

```
loadExternalScriptFile = function(filename) {
    var fileref = document.createElement("script");
    if (fileref){
        fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
        fileref.setAttribute("src", filename);        
        if (typeof fileref != "undefined")
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
    }
}

//dynamically load and add this .js file
loadExternalScriptFile("myscript.js");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try holding the read source in local storage as well, in a similar manner to:

```
// At startup, defaulting to permanent_settings
function onLoad() {
  LocalStorage['read_from'] = 'permanent_settings';

  // Other initialization work
  // ...
}

// When pressing Save
function onSaveClick() {
  LocalStorage['read_from'] = 'permanent_settings';
}

// When pressing Preview
function onPreviewClick() {
   LocalStorage['read_from'] = 'temporary_settings';
}

// When accessing the settings, read their source
function getSettingForKey(var key) {
   var source = LocalStorage['read_from'];

   // It can be either permanent_settings, or temporary_settings
   var settingsArray = LocalStorage[source];

   return settingsArray[key];
}
```

Comment: What if chrome crashes before changing read_from to permanent_settings at exit? I want the default option to be permananent settings with option to change to temporary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to load the script and even execute code when it's loaded. You don't even have to wrap the code in a `$(function(){ ... })` block:

```
$.getScript(chrome.extension.getURL("myscript.js"), function() {
    alert("myscript.js has finished loading");
});
```